# C++: Access base class member from a nested class (in the derived class)

Tags: c++, class, nested, radix

I currently have the following (simple problem).
I would like to access a public member of the base class from a nested class. Apparently it doesn't work that easily...
What is the correct solution here?

Do I have to pass *this to the nested class within the derived class?

Thank you for the food for thought!

```
#include <iostream>

class base
{
public:
    virtual void update() = 0;
    void drawCircle(const int& num) const { std::cout << "Base Clase: Circle " << num << " completed..." << std::endl; };
private:
};

class derived : public base
{
public:
    class nestedClass
    {
    public:
        void drawSomeCircle() const {
            drawCircle(1);  // does not work!
            drawCircle(2);  // does not work!
            drawCircle(3);  // does not work!
        }
    private:
    };

    void update() override
    {
        // make some graphic stuff
        myInnerNestedClass.drawSomeCircle();

        // access base class member drawCircle from here --> is working
        drawCircle(4);
    }
    nestedClass myInnerNestedClass;

private:
};

int main()
{
    derived oneDerivedClass;
    oneDerivedClass.update();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `nestedClass` has no special relationship to `derived` beyond needing to name it via `derived::nestedClass` in some cases (much like a namespace). So the possible answers to your situation are the same answers if `nestedClass` had not been nested and was any other class out in your program.

Comment: Yes, basically a nested class is a totally separate class, like any other separate classes, with just the bonus of seeing `protected/private` members of the outer one. If you know Java, then it's not like in Java, where every instance of a nested class gets a magic handle to outer class instance and where you can't create nested class instance without outer object. In C++ nested classes behave like `static` nested classes in Java.

Comment: The solution here is to forget about how classes work in Java (or C#). They don't work this way in C++.

Comment: You should rethink your design. Why do you try to use a nested class as a member of the outer class and why does the nested class need access to member functions of the outer claass? Making them mutually dependent on pointing to one-another comes with a bunch of problems on its own and if they can only exist in a pair, then why are they separate classes?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik in this case, in C# they work the same. Instances of fested classes are separate. It's only Java that has this magic built-in `OuterClass.this` pointer.

Answer (score 1):

> Do I have to pass `*this` to the nested class within the derived class?

**Yes**. `nestedClass` doesn't know to whom `drawCircle(const int&)` belongs unless it's in a global or outer `namespace` scope.

Once you pass a `*this` object of `derived` to `nestedClass`, it can even access its `private` members as well.